# Resultado inesperado en una sentencia al usar ALL

Tags: mysql, sql

He creado las siguientes tablas:

**productostest**

[image: Tabla productos]

**pedidos**

[image: Tabla pedidos]

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT nombre
FROM productostest
WHERE id = ALL (SELECT idProducto FROM pedidos WHERE cantidad > 0);
```

Esta consulta no devuelve ningún resultado. ¿Cual es el motivo? para todos los idProductos se cumple que tienen cantidades mayor que 0.

Según la documentación:

> La palabra **ALL**, que debe de seguir a un operador de comparación,
>   significa " devuelve TRUE si la comparación es verdadera para todos los valores
>   en la columna que devuelve la subconsulta".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás interpretando mal el funcionamiento de ALL. En este caso le estás pidiendo que compare cada *id* de la tabla **productostest** con todos los *idProducto* de la tabla **pedidos** y, si es igual a todos, devuelva el registro.

Entiendo que a vos te interesa que devuelva el registro si el *id* en **productostest** coincide con alguno de los *idProducto* devuelto por la subquery.

En ese caso, en vez del operador ALL, tenés que usar el operador ANY.

```
SELECT nombre
FROM productostest
WHERE id = ANY (SELECT idProducto FROM pedidos WHERE cantidad > 0);
```

---

MySQL tiene también el operador IN que también te permite realizar lo mismo:

```
SELECT nombre
FROM productostest
WHERE id IN (SELECT idProducto FROM pedidos WHERE cantidad > 0);
```